# How to filter only some rows of an array inside a document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection of documents, using a schema like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  images: [{
    uri: string,
    active: Boolean
  }]
});
```

I'd like to get **all** documents (or filter using some criteria), but retrieve - in the `images` array - **only** the items with a specific property (in my case, it's `{active: true}`).
This is what I do now:

```
db.people.find( { 'images.active': true } )
```

But this retrieves only documents with at least one image which is active, which is not what I need.

I know of course I can filter in code after the find is returned, but I do not like wasting memory.
Is there a way I can filter array items in a document using mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the aggregation you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: true,
      images: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$images",
          as: "images",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$images.active",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/t_VxjfiBBMK

Comment: The projection may be passed as second argument of find in mongo 4.4 (removing the $project key). This allows mongoose to return  mongoose documents and not plain json objects

Comment: @grodzi Good to know.

Comment: Wonderful. And may I use the standard `project` of find, to select which fields to return?
Because when I do:

      find(
        {
          ...filter,
        },
        {
          _id: 0,
          name: 1,
          images: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$images",
              as: "images",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$images.active",
                  true
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      )
      .sort({createdAt: 'descending'})
      .lean()
    ;
I get an error..

Comment: This is the error I get: `MongoError: Unsupported projection option: images: { $filter: { input: "$images", as: "images", cond: { $eq: [ "$$images.active", true ] } } }`

Comment: @MarcoS are you using mongodb 4.4?

Comment: @MarcoS You can use this project in find, but your mongodb has to support it. https://mongoplayground.net/p/D4Rsvc35N-p

Comment: No, I am using mongo 3.6.8

Comment: @MarcoS then aggregate is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks... I'll upgrade mongodb, for sure... I really find aggregate command in mongo3 too complex...